# Is a quantum circuit without measurements, a unitary operator?

Tags: quantum-circuit

Is it true that the whole circuit, viewed as a map from the input registers to the end is a unitary operator ?

Comment: If all your gates are unitary, then yes.  And most gates are unitary.  The primary non-unitary one that some systems have is "reset this qubit to 0".

Comment: depends what you mean exactly. Non-unitary operations are possible and often considered. But also, any such quantum operation can be represented as a unitary operation in a possibly enlarged space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are non-unitary operations other than measurement, such as introducing a qubit or discarding a qubit or reseting a qubit or applying noise to a qubit.